# typescirpt don't understand my validation function logicallay

Tags: typescript

Hello i wan't to check some object or array is empty or undefined or null
so i make a util func like this

```js
const isEmpty = (obj: Array<any> | undefined | null | object): boolean => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
  }
  if (!obj) return true;
  return true;
};
```

but look at this

```js
      if (!isEmpty(houseData)) {
          const { GetAllHouseForSuperUser } = houseData; // ⛔️ error here
      }
```

typescript told me

```
Property 'GetAllHouseForSuperUser' does not exist on type 'getAllHouseForSuperUser | undefined'.
```

but logically

houseData can't be undefined

how can i notice to typescript that houseData is not undefined ?

---

**UPDATE about interface**

```js
export interface getAllHouseForSuperUser {
  GetAllHouseForSuperUser: getAllHouseForSuperUser_GetAllHouseForSuperUser;
}

export interface getAllHouseForSuperUser_GetAllHouseForSuperUser {
  __typename: 'GetAllHouseForSuperUserResponse';
  ok: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  allHouse: getAllHouseForSuperUser_GetAllHouseForSuperUser_allHouse[] | null;
}
```

Comment: You can just write `if (houseData) {  }` It will check for `null`, `undefined`

Comment: @JoharZaman  I know but for learning purposes.  i wan't to use validation function  with typescirpt

Comment: How is `getAllHouseForSuperUser` looks like do you have a model for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't perform data flow through the function boundaries, it assumes that the signatures are accurate. That's why checks performed inside the function don't propagate outside.

There is a feature for this case, however: [type guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html). They can be user-defined as a functions returning special type referring to the one of their arguments. In your case, it would be written as such:

```
const isEmpty = (obj: Array<any> | undefined | null | object): obj is null | undefined => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
  }
  if (!obj) return true;
  return true;
};
```

Note that `obj is type`: it is the way to show that the boolean returned from this function has a meaning on the type level. Of course, it's up to you to check whether the implementation is correct.

Comment: `obj is null | undefined` makes no sense for the given implementation. `return obj === null || obj === undefined;` would